# Integrating with trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I am trying to integrate $$\int\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{x^2}\ dx$$ I am using the substitution $x=2\sin(\theta)$ and $dx=2\cos(\theta)\ d\theta$. I am a bit confused. If I put the $2$ on the $dx$ side,  I'll get: $\frac12\int\frac{\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}}{4\sin^2\theta}\ \cos\theta\ d\theta$. If I keep the $2$ where it is, I'll get: $\int\frac{\sqrt{4-4\sin^2\theta}}{4\sin^2\theta}\ 2\cos\theta\ d\theta$. These are very different!

Comment: If you insert $\mathrm dx /2 =  \cos(\theta) \mathrm d \theta$ into the integral, you get $\int \frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{x^2} 2 \frac{\mathrm dx}{2} = \int \frac{\sqrt{4 - \sin^2(\theta)}}{4 \sin^2(\theta)}2 \cos(\theta) \mathrm d \theta$$, which is the same.

Comment: When substituting $ x$ as $ x=f(t)$ you substitute for $dx$ with $dx=f'(t)dt$. So your second integral is the correct substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second integral which is correct: you have to express the integrand in function of $\theta$, and $\mathrm dx$ in function of $\mathrm d\theta$.  So you obtain 
2\cos$$\frac{2\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}{4\sin^2\theta}\,2\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$$
Furthermore, the substitution has to be bijective, so we add the condition
$$-\frac\pi 2\le \theta\le \frac\pi 2,\quad(i.e. \theta=\arcsin x),$$
and on this interval, we have $\cos\theta\ge 0$, so the  integral is ultimately, simplifying the coefficients:
$$\int\frac{|\cos\theta|\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta=\int\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\tan^2\theta}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you put $2$ on the $\mathrm dx$ side, you have $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}2 = \mathrm \cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$. Therefore, your integrand must become $$\int\frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{x^2}\cdot2\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}2$$ for the substitution. You still get $$\int\frac{\sqrt{4 - \sin^2\theta}}{4\sin^2\theta}\cdot2\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$$ in the end.